# Should I change the existing Listview in my app to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

Is there any advantages of converting the existing Listview in my app to RecyclerView??
Also when should I be using RecyclerView??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a tough question to answer. First of all: Think of the `RecyclerView` as the successor of the `AdapterViews` which comes with alot of useful improvement especially in the fields of animations for each item. Actually that's also what the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html) say:

> RecyclerView is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView. This
>   widget is a container for large sets of views that can be recycled and
>   scrolled very efficiently. Use the RecyclerView widget when you have
>   lists with elements that change dynamically.
>
> You also have the flexibility to define custom layout managers and
>   animations for this widget.

So in the future we'll probably don't use `ListViews` anymore. Furthermore the RecyclerView doesn't need anything like `"notifyDataSetChanged()"` when an item is added or deleted from your List, which is a huge improvement performance-wise.
If you wanna know more what Google means by saying *"more advanced and flexible version of ListView"* I'd recommend you to read this Blog-Post [A First Glance at Android’s RecyclerView](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/).

But to answer your questions explicity:

***Is there any advantages of converting the existing Listview in my app to RecyclerView?***
Yes. As already said the RecyclerView is much more flexible and comes with handy animations at no cost. (In terms of doing this on your own)

***When should I be using RecyclerView?***
Everywhere where a ListView is appropriate a RecyclerView is as well.

And an additional question:
***Is it necessary to switch from ListView to RecyclerView?***
At the moment absolutely  not! You have to consider that the RecyclerView isn't final at this point. So there may be some changes, bug-fixes and new features in the near future.
(As an example for a bug: `clipToPadding` doesn't work atm. Luckily it [has been reported](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=261) already)

Answer (score 1):

The *RecyclerView* will be the future, and it is more than a ListView2 and
the @reVeres's answer explain well the case.

It is the time to check the documentation and to do a little test, but it is not the time to switch, because the RecyclerView is the support-v21 and you can't use it in a production release.

Comment: What documentation?! I can't find it... Do you have a link to the official docs or API?